# Modified custom property given back from getPropertyValue in some cases

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables, custom-properties

I found a weired problem when working with custom properties.
Definition in css file:

```
--testprop: /test/01234;
```

When I access this property by calling

```
const style = window.getComputedStyle(window.document.body);
const testprop = style.getPropertyValue('--testprop');
```

the string value of testprop is set to **/test/1234**.

This means the characters **/0** are parsed browser internally to **/**.

When the custom property is defined like so:

```
--testprop: '/test/01234';
```

the javascript access results in a string value of **"/test/01234"** (something I expect).

Used browser: Chrome Version 97.0.4692.71 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)

Do I miss something here? I wouldn't expect the rewriting of **/0** in any circumstances.

Comment: Given, that everything in CSS should be a string, this looks like a bug in Chromium, as this issue can be reprocuded in Edge too, but not in Firefox.

Comment: On the other hand, why to store such a value in a CSS variable, it can't be used anywhere in CSS. You can't do anything like `background-image: url(var(--testprop));`. If the variable is purposed to be used as a JS variable only, it's not reasonable to store it as a CSS variable.

Comment: I Agree, it is a little bit specific. I just need the url and can only get it from a delivered css file. But anyway, the definitions for custom-property values do allow all the used character tokens as far as I understand the documentations.

Answer (score 0):

In fact this kind of problem is referenced in an existing bug report:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=661854